TypeScript error with OpenAI API: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' when filtering annotations
I'm parsing annotations from OpenAI Assistants responses and seeing this.
Error Message:
./node_modules/openai/src/_vendor/partial-json-parser/parser.ts:182:18
Type error: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

  180 |     try {
  181 |       while (jsonString[index] !== ']') {
> 182 |         arr.push(parseAny());
      |                  ^
  183 |         skipBlank();
  184 |         if (jsonString[index] === ',') {
  185 |           index++; // skip comma

My Code:
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY });

async function processMessage(threadId: string) {
  const messages = await openai.beta.threads.messages.list(threadId);
  const lastMessage = messages.data[0];

  if (lastMessage.role === 'assistant' && lastMessage.content[0].type === 'text') {
    const content = lastMessage.content[0].text.value;
    const annotations = lastMessage.content[0].text.annotations;

    if (annotations && annotations.length > 0) {
      // This is where the type error occurs
      const fileCitations = annotations.filter(
        (annotation) => 
          annotation.type === 'file_citation'
      );

      // Process file citations...
    }
  }
}

I've tried explicitly typing the result as a string array, as per this question
But this looks like a new issue relating to footnote types. Am I missing something?
Edit:
On version openai@4.60.1 and earlier the error changes to this:
./node_modules/openai/src/core.ts:619:3
Type error: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

  617 |
  618 | export abstract class AbstractPage<Item> implements AsyncIterable<Item> {
> 619 |   #client: APIClient;
      |   ^
  620 |   protected options: FinalRequestOptions;
  621 |
  622 |   protected response: Response;


Got there in the end. The trick was to explicitly use the FileCitationAnnotation type, and use a type predicate in the filter function:
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import { FileCitationAnnotation } from 'openai/resources/beta/threads/messages';

const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY });

async function processMessage(threadId: string) {
  const messages = await openai.beta.threads.messages.list(threadId);
  const lastMessage = messages.data[0];

  if (lastMessage.role === 'assistant' && lastMessage.content[0].type === 'text') {
    const content = lastMessage.content[0].text.value;
    const annotations = lastMessage.content[0].text.annotations;

    if (annotations && annotations.length > 0) {
      const fileCitations = annotations.filter((annotation): annotation is FileCitationAnnotation => 
        annotation.type === 'file_citation'
      );

      // Process file citations...
    }
  }
}

I'll leave the question up, since the answer to the post I linked above was slightly different.
